# use crontab to run a c++ program, "cin" does not wait for my input

Tags: c++, cron, cin

I am using the following C++ code(call it `test.cpp`). I just want to read an int from console.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "please make a choice" << endl;
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;
        if (!cin)
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "error"<< endl;
            usleep(1000);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "cin is: " << choice << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

When I manually execute it, it is fine and the console waits for my inputs. However, when I run it in crontab (command is like: `53 10 * * * /root/test`), it prints lots of stuff(like below). It seems like it ignores the "cin" and continue running. Does anyone have any idea why?

Should I not use `cin` when running in crontab? I know it does not make sense but I just try to figure out why.

```
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
please make a choice
error
```

Comment: Your code is fine, like you said it works when manually execute.  With crontab, it does work, cron ran your code waited for `cin` and jumped to ` if (!cin)` and print `error` .  Why are you using cron to run it, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Should the cron waits for cin? Why does it jump to the second line? I will probably remove the "cin" finally and just curious about the behavior.

Comment: add `usleep(1000);` after `cin >> choice;` to wait for input, if no input, the next within the time frame, next statement will fire and return `error`

Comment: If I'm not wrong, cron doesn't connect any file to the standard input, so cin finds an eof (or just an error) each time it tries to read, instead of a opened file without pending input, as happend when running from terminal.

Comment: `cron` doesn't have a terminal to read from - this is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

As [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) noticed in the comment, the cron doesn't attach any terminal to the standard input of the executed command. There is a reason for that. All commands executed by cron are running in *the background* without user intervention.

Normally all programs executed by cron are written in a way where they pull data to process from some file or database during execution. If you have to pass any data to standard input of your program, then you need to pass something there. For example:

```
53 10 * * * echo "Test" | /root/test
```